# Created record in CloudKit with CKAsset but the asset is always nil when fetching, other attributes are ok

Tags: ios, core-data, cloudkit, ckasset

I create a record in CloudKit using the CloudKit Dashboard. The record also contains an attribute for a photo, which I upload before saving the record.
The photo data is stored in an attribute of the type **CKAsset**.
In the entity core data date model it is represented as an attribute of type **Data**.

When I do a **NSFetchRequest** later on my local sqlLite DB which synchronises with **CloudKit** the attribute which is supposed to hold the binary data of the image is always nil.
All the other attributes - which are just strings - are filled with valid data. When I change these attributes and do a **NSFetchRequest** again the changes are reflected in the fetch result.

I have no idea why the photo attribute is always nil and the other string attributes contain the current valid value.

EDIT - sample code provided.

This is the code which fetches it from the local sqlite DB which is backed by CloudKit and where the photo attribute is **nil** even it is provided in CloudKit:

```
        let bgContext = self.newBackgroundContext()
        bgContext.perform {
            do {
                fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["title", "categoryValue", "date", "photo", "amount"]
                let results = try fetchRequest.execute() as! [ReceiptEntity]
                for record in results {
                    let title = record.title
                    let photo = record.photo
                    if let photo_local = photo {
                        log.info("| Photo attribute is present!!")
                    }
                }
               }
            } catch let error {
                let result: Result<[ReceiptEntity], Error> = .failure(error)
                cb(result)
            }
```

This is the Entity definition, generated by Xcode:

extension ReceiptEntity {

```
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<ReceiptEntity> {
    return NSFetchRequest<ReceiptEntity>(entityName: "ReceiptEntity")
}

@NSManaged public var additionalInformation: String?
@NSManaged public var amount: Double
@NSManaged public var categoryValue: String?
@NSManaged public var currencyValue: String?
@NSManaged public var date: Date?
@NSManaged public var placeMark: String?
@NSManaged public var title: String?
@NSManaged public var photo: Data?
```

}

As already mentioned before: When I fetch a certain record from CloudKit directly using the following code - the photo attribute has a CKAsset instance and the photo is there:

```
    privateDB.fetch(withRecordID: configRecordId) { (record, error) -> Void in
        let photo = record?.value(forKey: "CD_photo") as? CKAsset
        let title = record?.value(forKey: "CD_title") as? String
        
        if let url = photo?.fileURL {
            log.info("| Asset URL: \(url)")
        }

    }
```

Comment: I get the CKAsset when I fetch the record DIRECTLY from CloudKit using privateDB.fetch(withRecordID: ...) but it is nil when I fetch it using NSFetchRequest.execute(...).

The type of the photo attribute in the data model is of Data?.

Comment: do you have the Data attribute in your core data model? if not you should create this field in your model.

Comment: Hi! Yes I have an attribute called "photo" of type Data? in my model. I've created it using the Xcode-Modelbuilder.

Comment: okay nice, is the name of the attribute CD_photo in cloudkit dashboard ? and can you provide sample code how you are saving the photo ?

Comment: Yes - the attribute for the photo is called CD_photo in the CloudKit Dashboard and is of type CKAsset.

Please see the edited original post for code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem.
During the iteration of expanding my data model I added attributes manually in CloudKit using the CK dashboard and added the these attributes to my data model.

By adding a CKAsset attribute to CK named CD_photo. But this is wrong. The photo attribute should have had the type "Bytes" and then another attribute named CD_photo_ckAsset of type CKAsset.

But the easiest way to get it right is to let the **NSPersistentCloudKitContainer** by creating the schema of the App for you.